# Hodge theoretic mirror symmetry and DG-BV algebras

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, derived-categories, noncommutative-geometry, operads, mirror-symmetry

Consider two Calabi-Yau manifold $X$ and $\check{X}$ which are meant to be mirror partners. Motivated by "classical MS", In [DGBV Algebras and Mirror Symmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006123), the following enhancement is proposed:

**Conjecture (Cao-Jhou).** There exists a quasi-isomorphism of dg BV-algebras
$$ (\Omega^{*}(X),d_{DR},\wedge,(d^c)^*,\langle \bullet,\bullet\rangle) \simeq (\Omega^{-*,*}(\tilde{X}),\overline{\partial},\wedge,\Delta, \langle \bullet,\bullet\rangle_{Schouten-Nijenhuis} ) $$

(the details on how to construct the DG-BV structures on both sides and what is the meaning of each operator here appear loc. cit).

**Question.** This is maybe a trivial question... but:

1. Does anybody know how exactly is this expressed in terms of the Hodge-theoretic mirror symmetry in [Barannikov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010157.pdf), [Katzarkov-Kontsevich-Pantev](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.0107), and [Ganatra- Perutz-Sheridan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03839)?

In particular,

2. Is it expected that the proof of enumerative mirror symmetry from HMS follows the formal path explained in [The minimal model for the BV-operad](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.2008.pdf)? That is, we deduce from HMS a quasi-iso at the level of DG-BV algebras and then pass to the Frobenius/Hypercommutative level on homology via a Hodge-to-DeRham degeneration argument (which is a special case of the general phenomena for ''dg BV-algebra with non-commutative Hodge-to-de Rham degeneration" as in Theorem 7.8, there)?